# How can I send an error image if the image can't be found in cloudinary (default image?)

Tags: node.js, image, cloudinary

I want to send an image that might say something like "Image coming soon".

In gridFS I can find out if an image exists and if it exist send the image if not I could tell it to send an error image.

Is there a place in cloudinary that has a sort of default image to send if it can't find the image requested like via the `img src` tag.

I would like something better than a broken image.

I use nodejs

Answer (score 0):

When generating the image src URL with Cloudinary Node.js SDK, you can specify the `default_image` parameter:

```
cloudinary.image("non_existing_id.png", {default_image: "avatar.png"})
```

Or directly in the URL:

`http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/d_avatar.png/non_existing_id.png`

You can read more about this [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#using_a_default_image_placeholder).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work here is original img source. I use ejs template that's why you see `<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/div3r6wyw/image/upload/v1501197503/300x145/<%=comp.name%>-300x145.png" alt="<%=comp.name%>"` where should I put in the default (error image)

Comment: It looks like your image URL do not include the `default_image` parameter.

You need to upload some image that appears as your error image, named it "error_img" for example. then your URL should looks like that:

`src="http://res.cloudinary.com/div3r6wyw/image/upload/v15011‌97503/d_error_img.png/300x145/<%=com‌p.name%>-300x145.png‌​" alt="<%=comp.name%>"`